# How do I convert Apache rewrite rules to nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to convert these rules from Apache rewrite to nginx:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ api.php?version=$1&call=$2 [L]
```

I tried adding the following in the nginx config:

```
 rewrite ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ api.php?version=$1&call=$2
```

but I only receive a 404 error when I visit my site.

I want my URL to look like:

```
 http://mysite/1.0/Something
```

How can I convert these rules to nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `/` to your rewrite-destination and set the `last` flag.

```
rewrite ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /api.php?version=$1&call=$2 last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two converters, but double check the conversion output as well

http://winginx.com/htaccess

http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/